kubernetes liveness prob with database / external connectivity
We have rest api based app deployed in kubernetes cluster, planning to implemnent the liveness-prob check (http based /healthz GET endpoint).
Our is app dependent on database, is it good practice to implement the livenessprob with db connectivity check (or) we should just implement the health check endpoint without any external dependencies check.
I have referred the below documents:
https://microservices.io/patterns/observability/health-check-api.html
https://www.fairwinds.com/blog/a-guide-to-understanding-kubernetes-liveness-probes-best-practices

You can have a connectivity check from your application to the external DB and print the connection status code from the logs instead of having probes in this case

Having the liveness probe of application depend on status of external system is considered a bad practice. The main reason for that is, failures in one part of system can then spread to other parts of the system.
If you have large cluster, then database outage could lead to many Pods being killed, and spiking the cluster activity. This may lead to unnecessary instability, and issues.
On the other hand having the readiness probe of app depend on external systems is more acceptable, but still not great.
Ideally your App should be handling the error cases like this, and react correctly when DB is not reachable atx current time.

Liveness Probes: Used to check if the container is available or the container in a pod is still running. Since liveness focuses on application. If you use HTTP GET request to ‘/readyz’ which returns a 200 OK, then only the application is alive.
Readiness Probes: Used to determine if the application is ready to be used and handle the traffic. And also checks dependencies like DB connections or other services your container is depending on to fulfill its work.
The pod IPs are added to endpoints based on the pod's readiness check. If a pod's liveness check fails, it is deleted and its IP removed from the endpoint.
As your application will be trying to connect with the Database so if DB is not UP your application won't respond HTTP-OK so your application won't start, and readiness keeps failing for application. If you use HTTP GET request to ‘/readyz’ which returns a 200 OK, then only if the application and dependencies(ex:database) readiness will mark POD are ready. There is no extra requirement to set up the readiness for DB and based on that start POD.
For best practice, maintain a liveness probe simple and focus only on checking application’s status irrespective of its dependencies, use the readiness probe for checking dependencies(database) to ensure the application is fully prepared.
